# Dual screen set up to Nvidia GeForce GT 740 graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

My office PC had an Nvidia GeForce 210 graphics card with a DVI-I output (along with a VGA output) and I had my dual screen set up like:

- Monitor 1 - VGA to VGA
- Monitor 2 - VGA to DVI-I -> VGA adaptor

I've just upgraded to an Nvidia GeForce GT 740 graphics card which I now notice has a DVI-D output so I subsequently cannot plug my DVI adaptor into this.

I'm currently shopping for some additional cables/adaptors and anything else I might need but I am wondering if it is even possible to connect my second older VGA only screen to this new graphics card as the second monitor of a dual screen set up?

Here is some information on my monitors:

Monitor 1

- [AOC Q2778VQE](https://eu.aoc.com/en/products/q2778vqe) 27" running at 1920x1080 resolution
- Outputs: HDMI 1.4 x 1, VGA, DVI, DisplayPort 1.2 x 1

Monitor 2

- [AOC 936W](https://www.cnet.com/products/aoc-936swa-lcd-monitor-18-5/specs/)  18.5" running at 1366x768 resolution
- Outputs: VGA, USB

Eventually, I will be upgrading the second monitor to hopefully the same as the first but for now, I'm planning on connecting the first monitor up with display port to display port and the second monitor up with VGA to DVI (but because it is DVI-D, I am not sure if it will work)?

I'd welcome any recommended set ups / advice for my case, thanks in advance.

Comment: I've just realised actually, if I use display port to display port for the first monitor then that frees up the VGA output on the graphics card for me to simply use VGA to VGA for the second monitor... Which should work okay I take it?

Comment: Yes (to your comment)